# Difference between story and user story? Are they same?

Tags: agile

What's the difference between a user story and a story? Recently i created a user story and my product owner asks me to convert it into a story.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about Agile project management terminology. It should be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There is not 2 different concepts named "story" and "user story" in the Agile world. People often say "story" when they mean "user story" to make it quicker. So, maybe your Product Owner is referring to a terminology internal to your company or internal to a tool you would be using. Best way seems to ask him directly though.

Comment: I dont think she was referring to something internal to the company because in the JIRA there two separate issue type named "story" and "user Story". So she asked me to update the issue type in the JIRA.

Comment: ah... so we are talking about Jira Issue Type. Then I still think this is custom issue type designed for your internal need. The "issue type" field is customisable like explained in there: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+Issue+Type+Field+Values

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using a different terminology. Each user story has different sub-tasks assigned to it. May be in your world, you are calling each sub-task a story and that's why your product owner asked you to create a story and not a user story.

Agile is all about collaboration, why don't you ask him what he means?